# Copy/move linked file when changing model instance owner in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a very simple Image model

```
class Image(Model):
    owner = ForeignKey(User)
    img = ImageField(upload_to=image_file_path)
```

the `image_file_path` resolves to `<username>/images/` where `username` is the Image model instance's `owner.username`

Now, when using Django admin to change the owner of the image, I want the physical image file to be moved to the appropriate path, i.e. `<new_username>/images/`.

What is the simplest / "correct" way of doing this?

Edit:

A few thoughts after experimenting a bit

- `post_save` handlers: the idea is to make sure that the model is sane by moving the file into the correct place after the model changes. The problem is that if somthing bad happens – the file is missing / transfer errors out (e.g. if storage is on S3 and the connection is bad) / etc. – then you can end up in a loop trying to revert the change or end up with an inconsistent model / FS state
- Django admin action: this seems to be a safer way because you can just copy the file, check that it's OK, then change the model, check that it's sane, then delete the old file. If anything breaks you can abort and since this is manually initiated from the admin interface there is no chance of users experiencing inconsisten behaviour.
- `pre_save`: The same process as in 'Django admin action' could probably be used with `pre_save`, although if you abort due to problems then user experience suffers. On the other hand if copy / moving files is borked, users are not going to be able to upload anything anyway.

Is there a fourth way? Are there sanitizers for Models in Django?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `post_save` signal of your Image model. In the same way you can use `post_delete` to actually delete the image file when the record is deleted.

You can review the Signals documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/).

Comment: `post_save` has the problem that if the file transfer does not go through I have to revert the model change to keep everything sane. The reversion triggers another `post_save` -> possible loop

Comment: @Timo does `post_save` run when the image transfer fails? That doesn't seem intiuitive... But if it does you could always add an extra check to see if the image exists in the location you expect before attempting to move it,

Comment: the owner change triggers a save which just changes the owner, I want the image path (both in the model instance and on disk) to reflect this change. Moving / copying the image inside the `post_save` handler can fail and then I have an inconsistent state -> need to revert owner change -> may end up in loop.

Comment: @Timo in that case you may want to look at creating a custom `create()` method.